# Sometimes getting uninitialized constant Devise::CustomDevise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've customized the `registrations_controller.rb` and `confirmations_controller` of `devise`. And these controllers resides under custom_devise folder.

Sometimes my Registration and Confirmation works fine but sometimes it is showing `uninitialized constant Devise::CustomDevise` Routing error.

And a strange fix is whenever I edit `routes.rb` the error goes away (without actually adding anything in `routes.rb`).

My `routes.rb` for Devise:

```
devise_scope :user do
  scope :module => "custom_devise" do
    match 'company_user/complete_profile' => 'confirmations#complete_profile', via: :get
  end
end

devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
           :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/custom_devise/registrations",
                             :confirmations => "devise/custom_devise/confirmations"
                           }
```

I'm using below devise modules:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

P.S: I have checked around all similar answers in SO but none is helpful for me. So please comment before making this question duplicate.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing routes from `devise/custom_devise/registrations` to `custom_devise/registrations` and same for `confirmations` did the trick.